android version mismatch between visual studio and android settings
i got a new tablet with android 13 as it says in the software information. but when i conncet the tablet to my visual studio to test my xamarin.forms app, i get android 8.1 (api 27).and the app doesn't work though it works fine on my phone which is actually android 13. how can i know the exact version of my tab or make it android 13 (note that the tab's system info also states that it is updated to android 13 with no more updates)
